# Running rspec Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec

When I run $ rspec spec/ I receive this error:

```
You must use ANSICON 1.31 or later (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/) to use colour on Windows
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.7.1,but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.0.1. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/app2/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/app2/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/app2/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/app2/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/app2/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top
(required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7
.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7
.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7
.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `map'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7
.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load_spec_files'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7
.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7
.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7
.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'k in autorun'
```

I have rspec and rspec-core installed:

bundle show rspec

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-2.0.1
```

bundle show rspec-core

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1
```

What do I need to do to run rspec?

Comment: Did you try, as the message suggests, `bundle exec rspec spec/` ? If that works, consider bundle binstubs.

Comment: That works! Is there a way that I can run rspec without bundle exec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the solution is right in the error message:

> Consider using bundle exec.

So you type:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/
```

But that's twice as many characters to type! Can't have that! So consider [bundle install --binstubs](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/):

Do this once:

```
$ bundle install --binstubs
```

Now this "just works"

```
$ rspec spec/
```